# List Children request returns 504 with code "UnknownError"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We're trying to get the contents of a directory but each time we get a 504 response.

The query is GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0%2Fme%2Fdrive%2Froot%3A%2FArq%20Backup%20Data%2F5E564D3E%2D4697%2D4704%2DADD5%2D236484E0945D%2Fobjects%3A%2Fchildren?top=1000

The response headers include:

```
client-request-id: 87174db4-ab7e-4e73-9839-e273bf731a84
request-id: f486e6cc-7857-483c-8718-1cbb1c076678
timestamp: (null)
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"Canada East","Slice":"E","Ring":"2","ScaleUnit":"000","RoleInstance":"QB1PEPF00000F28"}}
```

The response body looks like:

```
 {
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2021-01-30T23:45:38",
      "request-id": "f486e6cc-7857-483c-8718-1cbb1c076678",
      "client-request-id": "87174db4-ab7e-4e73-9839-e273bf731a84"
    }
  }
}
```

This only happens for 1 customer. Any suggestions on what's going wrong here?
Thank you.

Comment: What is the I'd that you have in your request? If you have the directory id do something like this `/me/drive/item/directoryid?$expand=children`. See if it helps.

Comment: Does the above helped?